# Django: How to reduce inner joins on Model inheritance?

Tags: django

I have several models inheriting from a base model.
The fields in the base model are needed rarely, but Django keeps doing complex inner joins to retrieve those fields whenever I use any of the  inherited models.
How can I tell Django to avoid this ? I only need the fields in this model rarely.

Note: maybe only(..) would work(I didn't check), but I would need to add it in many places in the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [abstract model inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

In short, setting `abstract = True` in the base class' meta, makes Django using abstract inheritance, meaning each derived model will contain a copy of all the fields defined in the base model.

By the way, one of the Django's maintainers, Jacob Kaplan-Moss [has quite a strong opinion against concrete inheritance](http://www.jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/),

> model inheritance also offers a really
>   excellent opportunity to shoot
>   yourself in the foot: concrete
>   (multi-table) inheritance

and again:

> I’d strongly suggest that Django users
>   approach any use of concrete
>   inheritance with a large dose of
>   skepticism.

Personally, I have never had to use model inheritance at all; however, after reading that blog entry, I am quite convinced in trying to avoid concrete inheritance as much as possible.

Comment: Right. The problem I query and use the base class(the table) too..Otherwise I would avoided the inheritance altogether..

Comment: You could create an implementation of the base model, that would not add anything.

Comment: Seems Kaplan-Moss has strong opinion against inheritance.. I wish I've read this before implementing.

Comment: You're right, I've should have put it more explicitly in my answer. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the only possiblity to avoid this is either making your base class `abstract`, or you create some custom sql queries that don't hit the 'base'-table...